# configure rooms for MUC in ejabber

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I want to configure rooms in ejabberd server

> 1) Create Two Rooms with a Room Name by configuring ejabberd's config file
>
> ```
>   Room Names will be 1) visitors 2) native
> ```
>
> 2) Don't allow users  to create room
>   3) User can join any room those are configured over ejabberd server

so far i have configured following values in **mod_muc**

```
{mod_muc,      [
                  %%{host, "conference.@HOST@"},
                  {access, muc},
                  {access_create, muc_admin},
                  {access_persistent, muc_admin},
                  {access_admin, muc_admin},
                  {max_room_id,2},
                  {max_room_name,2},
                  {max_room_desc,300},
                  {default_room_options,
                  [
                       {persistent, true}
                 ]}
                 ]},
  {mod_muc_log,[

                 {access_log, muc},
                 {cssfile, false},
                 {dirname, visitors@mydomain.com},
                 {outdir, "/var/lib/ejabberd/muclogs"},
                 {timezone, universal},
                 {spam_prevention, true},

   ]},
```

i am passing following values from client interface of strophe

```
JID : user@mydomain.com
Password: userpassword
Room: visitors@mydomain.com
Nickname:user1
```

but i don't know where to specify two room names and configured them saperately in the file

with above configuration i am getting following response from server

```
<body xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/httpbind'>
    <presence xmlns='jabber:client' 
          from='user@mydomain.com' 
          to='user@mydomain.com/40570047311328899827978413' 
          type='error'>

    <error code='404' type='cancel'>
        <item-not-found xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
        <text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Conference room does not exist</text>
    </error>
    </presence>
    <presence xmlns='jabber:client' 
        from='user@mydomain.com/40570047311328899827978413' 
        to='user@mydomain.com/40570047311328899827978413' 
        type='error'>
        <priority>-1</priority>
        <error code='403' type='auth'>
            <forbidden xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
            <text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Room creation is denied by service policy</text>
        </error>
        <error code='404' type='cancel'>
            <item-not-found xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
            <text xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'>Conference room does not exist</text>
        </error>
    </presence>
</body>
```

In presence handler what i have noticed is my from id doesn't match my room id

Comment: You are sending the stanza to the wrong domain. Typically you should send them to chatroom@conference.yourdomain.com.

where chatroom == name of chatroom

so your Room should be in this case:

visitors@conference.mydomain.com